# CollectionView sections

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview and I want it to be of n section where each section has a ten of cells, my problem is: Maybe n equals thirty five, in this case I want to show 3 section with ten of cells and the last section with just five.

Comment: What about the rest of the sections if n = 35?

Comment: I dont want it to be declared, just need the last section to has a five or n%10

Comment: I didn't understand the condition. Last section = 5 cells and other sections = n%10 cells?

Comment: no,if have a 35 items i need sections to be (10,10,10,5), if 47(10,10,10,10,7).

Comment: Updated the code with required conditions.

Comment: thanks a lot my friend it is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If array count is 35 `return count/10` if `count%10` is 0 else return `count/10+1` in `numberOfSections` method

In `numberOfItemsInSection` method multiply current section with 10 and subtract from count. return min value of 10 or subtracted value

In `cellForItemAt` method multiply section with 10 and add row to get the array index

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var arr = Array(1...35)
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return (arr.count/10) + (arr.count%10 == 0 ? 0 : 1)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return min(10,arr.count - (10*section))
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? Cell
        let currentStr = arr[(indexPath.section*10)+indexPath.item]
        cell?.label.text = "\(currentStr)"
        return cell!
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, yes, I understood why it is working, I debugged the code and I understood that the `numberofiteminsection` function is called by the number of sections and in each call it return number that assign to the count of cells in current call.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply implement `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods and configure `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` method based on the each `section` for number of `cells`.

```
let n = 35 //It specify the total elements count

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return n/10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case (n/10):
        return (n % 10)

    default:
        return 10
    }
}
```

In the above code, the `collectionView` will have

- (n % 10) cells for `last section`
- 10 cells for `other sections`

Kindly clarify your conditions so I can update the code accordingly.

Comment: It creates 3 sections when n = 35. It gives [10,10,10] not [10,10,10,5]

Answer (score 1):

You can split the array into chunks using this extension

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

If count is 35 -> [10,10,10,5]

If count is 30 -> [10,10,10]

If count is 29 -> [10,10,9]

Then use the two dimensional array in collectionview delegate methods

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    let array = Array(1...35)
    lazy var chunkedArray = array.chunked(into: 10)

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return chunkedArray.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return chunkedArray[section].count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        print(chunkedArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use a var instead the number "10" ?